# Why Z3 does not solve problem with trivial solution

Tags: python, z3

The code below runs until the last line and remains stuck forever.
When `solve` is called with `justCheck`=`True`, the code just ask z3 to check that the solution `a=b=0` is correct. The question is why z3 cannot find this solution by itself (at least not in few hours) ?

I understand that for some problem this can happen, for example with SHA2(x)=0, I expect z3 to be able to check if I give it the right x but it will not be able to solve it. The problem here does not involve anything like that, and it is obvious to the human brain that a=b=0 is a solution (all operations are xor, rotate and addition, so if the starting state is 0 then it remains stuck at 0 and all outputs are 0).

```
#!python3
from z3 import *
import sys
bit64 = 0xffffffffffffffff

desiredOut1=0
desiredOut2=0

def rotl64(x, shift):
    return ((x << shift) | LShR(x, 64 - shift))  & bit64

def prng(state):
    #print(state)
    a = state[0]
    b = state[1]
    axorb = a ^ b
    newa, newb = (rotl64(a,55) ^ axorb ^ (axorb << 14)) & bit64, rotl64(axorb,36)
    return [newa,newb],(a+b) & bit64

def prngAcc(state,n):
    assert(n>0)
    state,out = prng(state)
    for i in range(0,n-1):
        state,o= prng(state)
        out ^= o
    return state,out

def refreshEntropyPool(state,n):
    state,el = prngAcc(state,n)
    state,eh = prngAcc(state,n)
    state[0] ^= el 
    state[1] ^= eh
    assert(len(state)==2)
    state.append(el)
    state.append(eh)
    return state 

def safePrng(state,n):
    if len(state)> 2:
        #inject entropy pool
        state[0] ^= state[2] 
        state[1] ^= state[3]
    else:
        #initialize entropy pool
        state.append(state[0]^state[0]) #0 with same type as state[0]
        state.append(state[1]^state[1]) #0 with same type as state[1]
    print(state)
    state = refreshEntropyPool(state,n)
    tmp,out = prng(state)
    state[0] = tmp[0]
    state[1] = tmp[1]
    return state,out

def safePrngDut(state):
    return safePrng(state,1)

def solve(dut, justCheck):
    a, b = BitVec('a', 64), BitVec('b', 64)
    s = Solver()
    initState = [a,b]
    state1,out1 = dut(initState)
    state2,out2 = dut(state1)
    s.add(out1 == desiredOut1,out2 == desiredOut2)
    if justCheck:
        s.add(a == 0, b==0)
    s.check()
    m = s.model()
    print("%s %s"%(hex(m[a].as_long()).upper(), hex(m[b].as_long()).upper()))

solve(prng,justCheck=True)
solve(prng,justCheck=False)
solve(safePrngDut,justCheck=True)
print("Z3 rocks so far")
solve(safePrngDut,justCheck=False) # stuck forever in this one
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `LShR`? *obvious to the human brain* does not spring to my mind looking through your code.

Comment: @AxelKemper LShR is Z3's Logical Shift Right. What is "obvious for the human brain" is that no matter what combination of XOR, ROTATE, SHIFT or ADD operation are done, if the inputs is 0 the output is going to be 0. Z3 does not seems to get it with the current code.